# Loading Images from Xcode Project Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a folder (untagged-data) in Xcode that consists of a lot of images (100). I am trying to load the images into my application but for some reason the path is not correct and I am not able to load. Here is the URL I get which I am trying to load.

```
file:///Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66763907-9153-443A-BA0E-D5CB6CC9280C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D3C77C63-CA3D-4238-8EAD-97B1DA15F2C6/MyApp.app/untagged-data/vessey.jpg
```

Here is the code which populates an array with the paths:

```
 guard let resourceURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL else {
            fatalError("Bundle not found")
        }

        let resourcePath = resourceURL.appendingPathComponent("untagged-data")

        let paths = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: resourcePath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

        for resourceURL in paths {
            let path = resourceURL.absoluteString
            self.images.append(path)
            print(path) 

        }
```

When I try to create an image it simply throws an exception:

```
//let img = UIImage(named: images[index])
        let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: images[index])
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Something like path not found. It is not able to load the path inside the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Open the path below path in safari to check whether path exists or not

```
 file:///Users/johndoe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66763907-9153-443A-BA0E-D5CB6CC9280C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D3C77C63-CA3D-4238-8EAD-97B1DA15F2C6/MyApp.app/vessey.jpg
```

If path exists then comment the below line in code

```
//let resourcePath = resourceURL.appendingPathComponent("untagged-data")
```

Comment: But that is the path inside the simulator and safari will not open it.

Comment: just try it. If path exist then it will open in Mac safari